# Assigning data from a file to a dictionary object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following lines in a text file called `factory.txt`

```
Path_Folder_Name = data/1009/192/81/XYPatters/
Cloud_Site = gs://machines/inventory
M_Engine_Path = /mnt/unit/09000/UK/
```

I am opening it in my Python script like this:

```
with open('factory.txt', 'r') as factoryInfo:
     Path_Folder_Name = (factoryInfo.readline().strip())
     Cloud_Site = (factoryInfo.readline().strip())
     M_Engine_Path = (factoryInfo.readline().strip())
```

How can I assign the data I am getting from the text file to a dictionary ?

I tried this, but it's not assigning the data correctly:

```
data = dict(
    Path = Path_Folder_Name,
    Cloud = Cloud_Site,
    Engine = M_Engine_Path)
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output ? Do you just need the values or full line from file into your dictionary value ?

Comment: @PrashantKumar Hi thank you, I just need to assign the values from the text file to the names in my dictionary...so like in my dictionary, `Path` would be `data/1009/192/81/XYPatters/` from the file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only the values after `=` sign from the text file:

Try this:

```
with open('factory.txt', 'r') as factoryInfo:
     Path_Folder_Name = factoryInfo.readline().strip()
     Cloud_Site = factoryInfo.readline().strip()
     M_Engine_Path = factoryInfo.readline().strip()

data = dict(
    Path = Path_Folder_Name.split("=")[1].strip(),
    Cloud = Cloud_Site.split("=")[1].strip(),
    Engine = M_Engine_Path.split("=")[1].strip())
```

Comment: what did you even change compared to the example?

Comment: Reading the line from file, it was assigning a tuple. I changed it to normal value

Comment: `x = ("asldf alsdh llkj".strip())` provides the same result as `x = "asldf alsdh llkj".strip()`, so I don't really know, even with `'\n'` at the end

Comment: Thanks for pointing. For strings it guess it is same with or without parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

data = {}

with open("factory.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        tokens = line.split("=")

        if len(tokens) != 2:
            raise Exception("Invalid config file")

        key = tokens[0].strip()
        value = tokens[1].strip()

        if key in data:
            raise Exception(f"key '{key}' is defined twice")

        data[key] = value

print(data)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow...how could I assign values in the text file to specific parts of my dictionary?